# HTML5 fixed size page

Tags: android, ios, html

I want to make an HTML page that fit on any portable device and fill the screen and dynamically sizes its content. Also it should work on iPhone and Android. And the users should not be able to resize the page.

I have tried these ideas:

- make the layout a  with width 100% but still the user can zoom in/out
- I have used DIV tags but it did not fill in the screen on the iPad but works well on the iPhone.

I hope you have a good idea to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already tried using percentages and are unhappy with the results, I recommend you look into using [CSS Media Queries.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) By determining the resolution your website is being viewed in, you can optimise it for each device specifically.

If you want to disable zooming for your website in mobile devices, make sure to add this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: The problem with percentages is that the user can still zoom in/out and I want to prevent that. Media Queries won't help me with that.

Comment: Use this in your mobile device code: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />